# send kendoGrid parameters(filters, sort) for file download

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I am trying to send my filters from a grid in order to export an excel file with the filters applied. I am new to kendo, and I am having difficulties sending the filters,page,sorting to the controller. Here is what i have so far :

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult List([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        //generating list to send to the grid

        return Json(list.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**View**

```
Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("tokenList")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
     // columns for the model   
    })
    .DataSource(d => d.Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(true)
        .Read(read => { read.Action("List", "Settings", null); })
    )
    .ToolBar(toolbar =>
    {
        toolbar.Template(
            @<text>

                         <a href="@Url.Action("ExportToExcel", "Settings", new { page = 1, pageSize = "~", filter = "~", sort = "~" })" class="export" onclick="onDataBound()">EXPORT</a>


             </text>
            );
    })
    .DefaultSetupForApp(<-this adds filtering, sortable, pageable).
Render(); 
}
```

And this is my JS function for getting parameters(I saw this piece of code somewhere else, and I am trying to adapt it, here is where i think i need help)

```
function onDataBound(e) {
    var grid = this;

    // ask the parameterMap to create the request object for you

    **I need some info on this part, nothing i found was very helpful**

    var requestObject = (new kendo.data.transports["aspnetmvc-server"]({ prefix: "" }))
    .options.parameterMap({
        page: grid.dataSource.page(),
        sort: grid.dataSource.sort(),
        filter: grid.dataSource.filter()
    });


    // Get the export link as jQuery object
    var $exportLink = grid.element.find('.export');

    // Get its 'href' attribute - the URL where it would navigate to
    var href = $exportLink.attr('href');

    // Update the 'page' parameter with the grid's current page
    href = href.replace(/page=([^&]*)/, 'page=' + requestObject.page || '~');

    // Update the 'sort' parameter with the grid's current sort descriptor
    href = href.replace(/sort=([^&]*)/, 'sort=' + requestObject.sort || '~');

    // Update the 'pageSize' parameter with the grid's current pageSize
    href = href.replace(/pageSize=([^&]*)/, 'pageSize=' + grid.dataSource.total());

    //update filter descriptor with the filters applied

    href = href.replace(/filter=([^&]*)/, 'filter=' + (requestObject.filter || '~'));

    // Update the 'href' attribute
    $exportLink.attr('href', href);
}
```

I just want to send the filters to the controller. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it. All i had to do was give the `var grid` to correct grid, like this :

`var grid= $('#tokensList').data('kendoGrid');`

Answer (score 0):

I do this way :

Here my grid toolbar template.

```
    <a class="k-button" id="export" href="Equipment/Export?page=~&amp;pageSize=~&amp;filter=~&amp;sort=~" title="Export to Excel">
        <span class="k-print" />
    </a>
```

Let me know in case of any problem.